# Portfolio Optimization with ETFs and Futures

Tags: portfolio-optimization, hedging, sharpe-ratio, etf, minimum-variance

I am looking to perform portfolio optimization with a single ETF (or two) and a VIX futures (with the possibility of adding an additional hedging instrument). Here are some features of my portfolio optimization:

- I calibrate the covariance matrix using a historical rolling window of 21 days (a month, essentially).
- I perform the rebalancing of weights with differently frequencies (daily, weekly and fortnightly). This means that everyday/5 days/10 days I compute my portfolio returns with new weights*realized returns for that day. The weekly and fortnightly returns are overlapping i.e. Monday to Friday for 1 weekly return, Tuesday to Monday for the next (same for fortnightly).
- Besides the normal case where I assume all my holdings are in a ETF, I sometimes add in a VIX futures and run a simple portfolio optimization between the two assets.
- I do this for both MVP (minimum-variance portfolio) and maximizing Sharpe ratio portfolio variants.
- Lastly, this process is ran for a historical time series of 3 years, say 2018 to 2020.

Many times, I obtain cases whereby my portfolio optimization allocates all my holdings to either the ETF or the VIX. This seems abnormal, should there be a restriction such that maybe I hold a minimum of 80.0% of my portfolio in the ETF? (I am asking with respect to financial intuition and not mathematical proofs).

Also, when I perform the portfolio optimization with the ETF and the VIX futures, my portfolio statistics (expected return, realized volatility, Sharpe ratio - all are annualized from daily to a year with the assumption of IID - *252 or *252^0.5) usually turns out worse, is this normal?

Comment: From a non mathematical standpoint, you don't have to optimize the portfolio with the hedge. Optimize the portfolio for the ETFs, then derive the risk parameters. Once you know the risks with the portfolio, you start thinking about what you can do to hedge that risk. Identify a intuitive solution to hedge, then optimize when and how much to hedge.

Comment: "Optimize the portfolio for the ETFs, then derive the risk parameters." - Are you talking about optimizing across multiple ETFs? (Because obviously you can't optimize within the same ETF) and what do you mean by risk parameters? (are you talking about realised volatility, delta etc.)

Comment: If you only have one ETF, then skip the optimization step since it doesn't make sense. Find what risks are associated with that ETF. One way of thinking about risk is the return drivers, so yes, volatility and delta are good to look at. Then think about what you can introduce to your portfolio in order to hedge that risk. 

If you have more then one ETF, then you can optimize the allocation across those before you derive the risk and return drivers. 

My main point is that you generally want to think about the hedging instruments (VIX derivatives, etc.) separately from the main allocations

Comment: Speaking from a less mathematically reliant approach

Answer (score 2):

I did the same experiment using yahoo finance to get charts.
I took the SPY, the VIX and third ETF for comparison.

First have a look at the volatility of the 3 vehicles:

[image]

You can see that the VIX has 10 times more vol that the ETFs... And when you know that the weight of a instrument $k$ in a MVP is more or less proportional to
$$\beta_k\over \sigma^2_k,$$
where $\beta_k$ is its beta relatively to the "market" (or your risk model), and $\sigma_k$ its idiosyncratic risk, it is natural that the VIX has a very small weight:

[image]

For details about MVP (and others), have a look at
C-A. L and Guillaume Simon. "[Portfolio selection with active strategies: how long only constraints shape convictions](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3405228)" Journal of Asset Management 22, no. 6 (2021): 443-463.

Comment: Thanks Lehalle, let me take a look at the paper!

Comment: @KaiSqDist in the paper you will have all the close-form formulae you can dream of... but of course there are not such formula for everything. Nevertheless in a factor model it is feasible to understand a lot of effects, including the one you observed.